# MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Что делает данный код

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

Я правильно понимаю, что при экспорте нужно будет писать так:

```
#define MYDLL_EXPORTS

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

А при импорте так:

```
// #define MYDLL_EXPORTS

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Comment: Тебя одинаковые ветви if-else не смущают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это же макрос (текстовая замена), препроцессор проведет соответствующие условию в макросе замены а потом компилятор, в случае экспорта, пометит соответствующие имена функция как экспортируемые.